Did Mayor Humdinger actually steal the election in Paw Patrol: the Movie?
In Paw Patrol: the Movie Mayor Humdinger has become mayor, being the only person left on the ballot, with some implication that he's cheated.

Shortly after being called by Cap'n Turbot to rescue a truck driver who has crashed through a suspension bridge, the PAW Patrol receives a message from a dachshund named Liberty, who informs them that their arch-nemesis Mayor Humdinger has just taken over nearby Adventure City in a fixed election. Chase initially refuses to go, as he has PTSD from being lost in the city when he was younger, but Ryder assures him everything will be fine.

From the transcript:

Marty:    In a surprising twist, the leading candidate has dropped out of the race, leaving only one name on the ticket: Mayor Humdinger, who has just won by default.

....

Mayor Humdinger:  I want to start off by thanking each and every one of you for choosing me to be your new mayor.
Woman:  You were the only name on the ballot!
Mayor Humdinger:    You could only vote for one name anyway, so what does it matter? I won this election fair and square. Well, maybe not fair, but who’s keeping track?

Is it ever clarified exactly what he did? Did he just luck out with the resignation? Was there a deleted scene where it's indicated that he forced the other candidate out of the race, or that they were merely his catspaw before they dropped out on his request?

I have emailed and twitted at the screenwriters and director. Hopefully they'll answer this one.

@Valorum: I'm guessing they never replied?

Sadly, they did not.

And I have since learned that my "answer" relies on wiki entries made up from whole cloth. :-/

Ah, oops. I should have spotted that; https://www.reddit.com/r/PawPatrol/comments/1g492sr/was_there_a_directors_cut_of_the_first_paw_patrol/
